# Mongoose, como ordenar búsqueda por campo de otra colección

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto `NodeJs` y base `MongoDB`. Para manejar los querys dentro de `NodeJs` estoy usando `Mongoose`. Ahora me encuentro estancado en un intento de ordenar el resultado de una búsqueda por un campo que se encuentra en otra colección:

Ejemplo

Colección “Usuario”

```
`{ “_id” : ObjectId(“525ab02933b01a66b9dcbc5b”), “nombreUsuario” : 
“usuario_01”, “clave” : “123456”, “rol”:ObjectId(“09bab02933b01t16b9dc12b4”)}

{ “_id” : ObjectId(“525ab02933b01a66b9dcbc6b”), “nombreUsuario” : 
“usuario_02”, “clave” : “789123”, “rol”:ObjectId(“09bab02933b01t16b9dc12b5”)}`
```

El Rol se encuentra en otra coleccion

```
`{ “_id” : ObjectId(“09bab02933b01t16b9dc12b4”), “nombreRol” : “Administrativo”, “nivel” : 3}

{ “_id” : ObjectId(“09bab02933b01t16b9dc12b5”), “nombreRol” : “Cajero”, “nivel” : 4}`
```

como hago para ordenar un listado de usuarios por el campo “nivel” que esta en la coleccion “Rol”

```
Usuario.find()
.populate(‘rol’)
.sort(???? por campo nivel que esta en Rol ???)
.exec(...)
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo usando aggregation, primero usa $lookup para unir y después aplicas el sort. Mongoose también acepta aggregation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584665/mongodb-apply-sort-to-lookup-results?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Antes de nada deberías indicar las versiones sobre el software que trabajas o usas para así darte una mejor respuesta.

Ante la duda que tienes, si usas una versión 3+ (juraría que era a partir de esa versión) puedes usar la opción "aggregate".

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
db.students.aggregate(
    {$project: { postcode: 1 }}, 
    {$group: {_id: '$postcode', students: {$sum: 1}}}, 
    {$sort: {students: -1}}
)
```